# When are google-play-services classes not available on Android?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to look up the Google Advertising Id in a jar I'm going to distribute to third parties, but in development, I realized `google-play-services.jar` might not always be on the classpath, and I'd have to use reflection to avoid a `ClassNotFound` exception when interacting with `AdvertisingIdClient`.

Is this a problem I should actually worry about? Under what circumstances would the Google Play Services classes not be on the classpath?

Comment: If it's bundled with your app, then why wouldn't it be available?

Comment: Since I'm just distributing a library, I guess the question is when wouldn't someone else bundle it? And it's not available on the class path by default?

Comment: I think you should make your library depend on it. Then you don't need to worry if others include it or not

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies in your app's build.gradle dependencies and try

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```